# Active Drives and Spare Drives (RAID10)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-10.04, software-raid

I'm setting up software RAID on Ubuntu Server 10.04; specifically RAID10. It's asking for the number of active devices for the array and the number of spare devices.

I know RAID10 is two mirrored pairs; RAID0 for two sets of RAID1 arrays (correct me if I'm wrong).

I would just like to know if all the devices (I'm using 4) are considered active, or if I should be setting it as 2 active and 2 spare.

Comment: Keep in mind that a Linux software RAID10, isn't exactly a RAID10, it can be setup really weird in various configurations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10

Comment: Didn't know that... it does say that the "4-drive example is identical to a standard RAID-1+0 array". So does that mean software RAID is going to be an okay choice in this case?

Comment: The software RAID runs just fine, though if you are worried about high-performance, you may need a hardware RAID controller.  Do some testing after you have the software RAID setup to see if it meets your requirements.  I use the software RAID on many servers, but they aren't extremely critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a RAID configuration, a *spare* or *hot spare* is an extra drive that at array construction stores nothing. If at some time in the future, an *active* drive fails, **md** (or whatever RAID controller you are using) will automatically start restoring data from the *active* drives to one *spare* drive in order to replace the spare drive.

If you have a RAID 10 of five 1TB disks (four active and one spare), you will only have 2TB total capacity. This is because you have a stripe of 2TB, which is mirrored so your 3rd and 4th disks are used up, and the fifth disk does nothing until one of the four fails.

[Wikipedia RAID#Hot Spares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Hot_spares)

Answer (score 3):

All 4 are active.  Spares are referring to Hotspares, which take over in the event of a disk failure.

Answer (score 0):

Spares are usually on-line drives not currently part of the RAID set.  If one of the drives fails, the RAID set can automatically rebuild using a spare.

In your example, all are active.